# Error a la hora de importar pyautogui

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de programar el juego del buscaminas. He decidido usar pyautogui para detectar donde y cuando se hace click, pero al importarlo me saltan los siguientes errores:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/env-01/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyautogui/_pyautogui_osx.py", line 5, in <module>
         import Quartz
       File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/env-01/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Quartz/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
         import AppKit
       File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/env-01/lib/python3.9/site-packages/AppKit/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
         import Foundation
       File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/env-01/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Foundation/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
         import CoreFoundation
       File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/env-01/lib/python3.9/site-packages/CoreFoundation/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
         import objc
       File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/env-01/lib/python3.9/site-packages/objc/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
         from . import _objc
     ImportError: dlopen(/opt/anaconda3/envs/env-01/lib/python3.9/site-packages/objc/_objc.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libffi.8.dylib
       Referenced from: /opt/anaconda3/envs/env-01/lib/python3.9/site-packages/objc/_objc.cpython-39-darwin.so
       Reason: image not found
        
     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
        
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "/Users/administrador/Desktop/VISUAL_STUDIO_CODE/Pruebas/pruebas.py", line 1, in <module>
         import pyautogui
       File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/env-01/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 166, in <module>
         from . import _pyautogui_osx as platformModule
       File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/env-01/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyautogui/_pyautogui_osx.py", line 7, in <module>
         assert False, "You must first install pyobjc-core and pyobjc: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html"
     AssertionError: You must first install pyobjc-core and pyobjc: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html
```

He buscado en foros a ver si encontraba a alguien que le ocurría lo mismo, pero no encuentro nada parecido. Las respuestas que encuentro es a gente que no lo había instalado correctamente, pero yo lo hice utilizando `conda install -c conda-forge pyautogui`, cosa que según el sitio web de anaconda esta bien. También he probado a instalar pyobjc-core y pyobjc (la solución que me da el segundo error), pero al hacerlo me dice que ya lo tengo instalado.
Soy bastante nuevo en el mundo de la programación y esta es mi primera vez escribiendo en un foro, así que cualquier ayuda la apreciaría bastante.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: El error dice: _You must first install pyobjc-core and pyobjc: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html_. ¿Has probado con esto?

Comment: Para extender un poco mi comentario anterior, `pyobjc` es un paquete para Objective C (y que se usa en Mac). Considero que deberías instalar `pyobjc` antes de instalar `pyautogui`, quizás eso resuelve tu problema :)

Comment: @DiegoRamirez lo acabo de intentar con `pip3 install pyobjc` y con `python3 -m pip install pyautogui`, pero me dice que ya lo tengo todo instalado y sigue saliendo el error. Gracias por responder :)

Comment: ¿Cuántas versiones de Python tienes? Eso nos puede ayudar.

Comment: He visto que tenía la versión 3.9.7, lo he actualizado a la 3.10.0 y ya no me sale este error. Ahora me sale este `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautogui'`

Comment: Las versiones que tengo son: 2.7.10, 3.8.5, 3.8.8, 3.9.7 y 3.10.0

Comment: Eso pudo ser el problema. Ya te he dejado una respuesta, basándome en tus comentarios.

Answer (score 1):

En base a los comentarios, podemos llegar a la siguiente conclusión: **has mezclado tus instalaciones de Python**.

Puede que los atajos `pip`, `conda`, `pip3`, `python` y `python3` se refieran a diferentes versiones de Python. Hay una forma sencilla de resolverlo, si deseas conservar todas las versiones.

En vez de usar, por ejemplo, `pip3 [opciones]`, usa `python3.10 -m pip [opciones]`. Y a la hora de correr tu script, corre `python3.10 [archivo]`. Así conservas todo en su sitio.

Por supuesto, puedes usar `python3.8` o `python3.9` en vez de `python3.10`. ¡Solo asegúrate de instalar paquetes y correr código con el mismo Python!

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Pues, si te fue útil, puedes marcar esta respuesta como aceptada :)